# CoffeeScript not working with -w option

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Folks,
  If I add the following to my package.json file, I get these errors whenever I make a saving change to any of the files.  Application I have is dead simple test, nothing special.

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "coffee -w app.coffee"
}
```

error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
  at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
  at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039:14)
  at listen (net.js:1061:10)
  at Server.listen (net.js:1127:5)
```

app itself:

```
express = require('express')
jsonFun = require('./jsonFun')
returnObjects = require('./returnObjects')

app = express()

exports.app = app

app.configure () ->
    app.set 'view engine', 'jade'
    app.use express.bodyParser()
    app.use express.logger('dev')
    app.use app.router


app.get '/hello/:name', (req, res) ->
    returnObjects.returnResult(req.params.name, res)

app.get '/file/sync/:fileName', (req, res) ->
    jsonFun.syncJSON(req, res)

app.get '/file/async/:fileName', (req, res) ->
    jsonFun.asyncJSON(req, res)


app.listen 3000
console.log "Listening on 3000..."
```

Comment: Are you stopping the old server before starting the new one?

Comment: how do i check this? :)

Comment: no, i guess not, i was expecting node to restart itself on every code change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) (or Forever I think) will work well here. This is my dev watcher script:

```
#!/bin/bash
nodemon ./app/webserver.coffee logLevel=debug
```

Comment: wait, isnt this exactly what we dont want to do, and the -w option in node is for?

Comment: kinda, but nodemon will stop the existing server and start a new one; -w might not be doing that